# how to extract all the data between &nbsp;

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
<p align="JUSTIFY"><a href="#abcd"> Mr A </a></p>
<p align="JUSTIFY">I </p>
<p align="JUSTIFY"> have a question </p>
<p align="JUSTIFY">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="JUSTIFY"><a href="#mnop"> Mr B </a></p>
<p align="JUSTIFY">The </p>
<p align="JUSTIFY">answer is</p>
<p align="JUSTIFY">not there</p>
<p align="JUSTIFY">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="JUSTIFY"><a href="wxyz"> Mr C </a></p>
<p align="JUSTIFY">Please</p>
<p align="JUSTIFY">Help</p>
```

I want to iterate the extraction of the data with the help of `&nbsp;`.

- The first iteration should display *I have a question*
- second iteration should display *The answer is not there*
- The person names should also be extracted in a different list ..for example ['Mr A','Mr B','Mr C']

If someone has any idea how to do it, it might be useful because I am trying to learn python got stuck with this problem.The code i tried is

```
for t in soup.findAll('p',text = re.compile('&nbsp;'), attrs = {'align' : 'JUSTIFY'}):
    print t
    for item in t.parent.next_siblings:
        if isinstance(item, Tag):
            if 'p' in item.attrs and 'align' in item.attrs['p']:
                break
            print item
```

It return [] which is not what want

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I wouldn't consider parsing HTML a particularly good choice for "learning Python" - what concepts are you already familiar with, what approaches have you already tried, what ideas have you come up with so far?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for a brief guidance. The code i tried is to first find all '&nbsp' but it returns []                                        print soup.findAll('p',text = re.compile('&nbsp;'), attrs = {'align' : 'JUSTIFY'})

Comment: @JonClements I am familiar with BeautifulSoup and some basic coding in python. Do you think using Regex for searching  '&nbsp;' will be a good idea? because i tried writing regex but it showed the same result as i mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another method using Regex:

```
from re import sub

html = '<p align="JUSTIFY">I </p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY"> have a question </p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">&nbsp;</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">The </p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">answer is</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">not there</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">&nbsp;</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">Please</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">Help</p>'

print [sub("\s+", " ", x).strip() for x in sub("<.*?>", " ", html).split("&nbsp;")]
```

output:

```
['I have a question', 'The answer is not there', 'Please Help']
```

Comment: @iCodez-Thank you very much for the reply, it does separate when it finds '&nbsp;' and i can loop the results as the way i want. Thanks a lot

Comment: @iCodez-But in beginning of every element in the list it displays &#9;   I am trying to get rif of it,but thanks a lot

Comment: @user2657822 - That is very strange and I'm afraid I can't really help you with it.  Your data must be different than that given.  However, you could always try something like `[x.replace("&#9", "") for x in l]` where `l` is the list.

Comment: @iCodez- Yes, this one works good and removes the special characters in the beginning. My original code is a little different than the one i posted, i just wanted to make my question simpler so i posted a matching example. Because thats what i was suggested to do. I have edited my code a little bit to include <a> tag and would like to learn the answer to the newly edited questions. Please don't mind as i am writing python only for a week now.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = ""

html = '<p align="JUSTIFY">I </p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY"> have a question </p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">&nbsp;</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">The </p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">answer is</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">not there</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">&nbsp;</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">Please</p>\
<p align="JUSTIFY">Help</p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
title = soup.findAll("p", {"align" : "JUSTIFY"})

for i in title:
    s += ''.join(i.contents)

f =  s.split("&nbsp;")
for i in f:
    print i
```

Comment: @ton1c-Thank you for the idea. I tried it , but received error as      TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, Tag found       at l.append(''.join(i.contents))

Comment: @ton1c-I tried with the edited code. Actually in my real code there are subtags inside the p tag, do you think this might be the problem?